# return в функции(методе) в laravel php

Tags: php, ооп, методы

Есть два метода в классе
Приближенный пример кода

```
function name1 (){
 $a = 1
 $b = 2
 $send = $this->name2($a, $b);
 $c = $item;
 return $c;
}  

function name2($a, $b){
 $item = $a + $b;
 return $item;
}
```

Вопрос, почему выдаёт

> Undefined variable: item

и как исправить чтобы заработало.
P.S. Функцию `name1` вызывают из вне.

Comment: А откуда в `name1` взяться `$item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$c = $item; (меняем на) $c = $send;
```

Почитайте про область видимости

Так, тут все-таки сложнее немного с пониманием, судя по комментариям. На пальцах:

Методы - это люди, люди могут передавать друг другу вещи и люди решают, что с этими вещами делать.

name1 - Вася
name2 - Петя
инициализация - Мама

Мама отдает Васе 2 монеты (аргументы): 1 рубль ($a) и 2 рубля ($b), и говорит: "Посчитай". Но Вася не умеет считать, потому что ему 1 год, но он хитрый, и знает, что считать умеет Петя, он отдает ему эти монеты ( `$send = $this->name2($a,$b)`, просит посчитать. Петя считает сумму и говорит Васе значение (`return $a + $b`). Вася получает это значение и передает маме. ( `return $send` );

Comment: И это будет наш return $item; из name2?

Comment: @Domilola return $item присваивается переменной $send в методе $name1

Comment: Undefined variable: send

Comment: @Domilola вы либо код в вопросе неверный предоставили, либо поменяли что-то не то. Если Вы присваиваете переменной $send значение, полученное из метода `name2` то в переменной $send будет то значение, которое нужно вернуть в методе `name1`

Comment: Вы правильно написали, это я уже не там заменил, вы мне помогли спасибо Вам.